# pgadmin4 wont work in specific location behind nginx

Tags: nginx, pgadmin-4

I got some trouble: pgadmin working perfect behind nginx in location /, but it wont work behind location /pgadmin
Work great:

```
location / {
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;

         proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5050;
}
```

Wont work:

```
location /pgadmin {
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;

         proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5050;
}
```

May be i need some specific rewrite?

Comment: Change `/pgadmin` to `/pgadmin/` and `http://127.0.0.1:5050` to `http://127.0.0.1:5050/` and see if it works

Comment: no, it doesnt. I have this try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For version [**pgAdmin 4 v3.0**](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/), until the issue is actually fixed, here's a quick command-line **hack** based on [this](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3149).

```
cat > quickfix.txt <<THE_END
class ReverseProxied(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        script_name = environ.get("HTTP_X_SCRIPT_NAME", "")
        if script_name:
            environ["SCRIPT_NAME"] = script_name
            path_info = environ["PATH_INFO"]
            if path_info.startswith(script_name):
                environ["PATH_INFO"] = path_info[len(script_name):]
        scheme = environ.get("HTTP_X_SCHEME", "")
        if scheme:
            environ["wsgi.url_scheme"] = scheme
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
app.wsgi_app = ReverseProxied(app.wsgi_app)

THE_END

sudo sed -i '/app = create_app()/r quickfix.txt' /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
rm quickfix.txt
```

The commands above insert a piece of code into the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py`, right after the line `app = create_app()`.

Also, make sure the path to `pgAdmin4.py` on your system is correct. You may need to adjust the snippet above.

Then, configure nginx as follows:

```
location /pgadmin-web/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5050/;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Script-Name           /pgadmin-web;
}
```

For reference, also have a look at [pgAdmin4.py](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/web/pgAdmin4.py) on GitHub.

Comment: Did you ever send in a patch for this dearly missed functionality? The tool is almost useless in Docker containers without proper support for subpaths. I'd expect to be able to just pass `PGADMIN_PATH_PREFIX=/pgadmin4` in an env variable....

Comment: It looks like 4.4 will contain this fix to add support for SCRIPT_NAME as per https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BOCxozKrZb%2BMMbmvVYHPRr28CZgFCSfTQ%3DN9HiySxCuxNX_HQ%40mail.gmail.com.

Comment: With latest pgadmin4, below NGINX config solves the problem.
```proxy_set_header    X-Script-Name           /pgadmin-web;```

Comment: @AndyC can confirm, this works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 5):

The fix seems to be not needed anymore.

According to Redmine issue, SCRIPT_NAME env var could be used (at least with latest official docker image).

Docker Compose snippet from the issue (working for me):

```
version: "3" 

services:

  pgadmin4:

    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest

    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=bla@bla.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=thepwd
      - SCRIPT_NAME=/pgadmin4

    volumes:
      - pgadm:/var/lib/pgadmin

    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true" 
      - "traefik.backend=pgadmin4" 
      - "traefik.frontend.priority=600" 
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Method:GET" 
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/pgadmin4"      

  postgis:
    image: mdillon/postgis:9.6-alpine

    volumes:
      - pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    expose:
      - 5432

    env_file:
      - pg.env

    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false" 

volumes:
  pgdb:
  pgadm:
```

Comment: Using `SCRIPT_NAME=/pgadmin` worked for me, however, for use within Rancher 1.6 I only had to set `traefik.enable=true`, `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:xxx;PathPrefix:/pgadmin` and `traefik.port=80`, everything else broke it to some extend.

Comment: Yes `SCRIPT_NAME` env **works** with [latest pgadmin 4.11](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4). Easier to proxy behind Traefik. [uWSGI+Nginx setup](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/server_deployment.html#nginx-configuration-with-uwsgi) is an overkill just to use a subfolder.

Comment: Adding SCRIPT_NAME like mentioned in these examples gives me a 500 internal server error. I'm also using Traefik and PgAdmin 4.11 and I already have other applications running behind Traefik. Anyone has another suggestion what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in pgAdmin4 version 1.6, It is fixed now and will be available in next release.

Ref: [Link](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2563)

Comment: it seems like in version >1.6 it will be solved. Thank you!

Comment: pgAdmin4 v2.0 released today.

Comment: still the same, ill try to make clean install ( not update from 1.6 )